# Can I copy Clipboard text to terminal in linux use shutcuts

Tags: bash, shortcut

For example: I want to download a pdf file, and the url is save in clipboard. How can I use `wget url` to download this file quickly? I do not want to use mouse.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

if you want copy a url from windows to a vm linux, you should install vmtools first.

Comment: yeah! Shit + Ctrl + V paste your Clipboard content to bash.

Comment: FYI it has nothing to do with bash but with your terminal